# When Google Map generates events

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My javascript function looks more or less like this:

```
function drawMap(data) {
      var mapOptions = { mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), mapOptions);
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      // Add some markers to 'bounds'
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      map.panToBounds(bounds);

      map.addListener("bounds_changed", function() {
        console.log("changed");
      });
    }
```

It seems that whatever event I use in `addListener` my handler function is triggered during page loading. I'd expect that this code will first fit to bounds and only then start listening to events. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of many of the events associated with a map, quite a few of them are first triggered when the map is initially loaded.

A really great example of this can be seen [here on the Google Developer page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events).

As you can see from the example, `bounds_changed` is one of the events triggered when you first load or refresh the page.

Comment: I understand that it should be fired, but I'd expect it to happen before I call `addListener`. For some reason it happens later. How can I workaround this and handle "bounds_changed" only after the initial load?

Comment: @Filip What exactly are you hoping to accomplish when the event triggers? Maybe there is another event that would be better for what you're going for.

Answer (score 0):

The `map.fitBounds` function is asynchronous, it is queued to run when you call it, but doesn't actually affect the map until after you set up the listener. Most people want the event listener function to run as a result of the `fitBounds` function